# On my TYPO3 Website, columns are showed as rows

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

I use Gridelements for my TYPO3 Page, after i updated from 8 to 9 LTS, columns are showed as rows.
Anybody knows how to solve this Problem?

I tried to change the settings for gridelements, like i tried 2,3,4 columns, i also try to change the order of the elements, nothing helped.
In the developer-tools from Edge, it seems like it has no columns

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yn13.png]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap and updated it from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 the columns have to be wrapped by a row. In Bootstrap 4 it is working without. Or maybe your CSS is the reason.